# How does ASP.NET HttpRuntime.Cache automatic removal work?

Tags: asp.net, caching

Scenario:

i have a HttpRuntime.Cache \ System.Web.Caching.Cache filled with objects.

All objects have the same expiration and the same priority. If the System reaches the 99% memory usage limit then automatic cache item removal starts. (right? configurable?) How the cache will be cleaned in my scenario? Will a) all items be removed because of same expiration / priority or will b) some random items be removed?

greetz 
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all items have the same priority and expiration, the ASP.NET cache uses a Least Recently Used algorithm to determine which items to evict from the cache.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx#scalenetchapt06_topic14)